# Enable authentication plugins with security.json in solr 5.2

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper

I am not able to upload security.json to zookeeper, zkcli throws below exception-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NoNodeException: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /etc/installer/security.json
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:111)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:783)
        at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$9.execute(SolrZkClient.java:380)
```

Here is my security.json:

```
{
"authentication":{
"class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
"credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0=
Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}
},
"authorization":{
"class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
"permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",
"role":"admin"}]
"user-role":{"solr":"admin"},
}}
```

Command to upload json to zookeeper:

```
bash /opt/solr/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:5181/lws-map -cmd put /etc/installer/security.json '{"authentication": {"class": "org.apache.solr.security.KerberosPlugin"}}'
```

I am following steps from [solrwiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Authentication+and+Authorization+Plugins) . did I miss any steps? please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Try to execute

```
bash /opt/solr/server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:5181/lws-map -cmd makepath /etc/installer/
```

and then execute the `put` command